# leaving and revisting a scene keeping any user input changes the same. Can it be done?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory, input

[image]Hi Im relatively new to flash developing and i have a quick question about saving user input. I have a maze scene whereby the user navagates a character around until confronted with another object, when the character hits the object a new scene is opened promting the user to pick a solution to a problem. Once the user clicks the correct answer a box appears saying return to the maze, however when clicked and returned to the maze the character starts back in its original postion, where as I would like the scene to resume where it left off, ie the character is at the point where it collided with the object, the object has dissappeared and the character can resume on the same course.
Thanks for giving this a read I hope it makes sense and some one has a solution for me.
I did have some nice images to explain it better but apprently i need 10 reputation points to upload those.

EDIT: First Id like to say thanks for the rep points you bunch of stars and secondly I know using scenes in flash is seriously cr*p practice and outdated but its the way I learnt all those years ago and seen as Flash itself will be outdated soon Im not really looking to learn another approach using sprites or frames, I just kind of want a fix for this way if poss thank you for answering!

EDIT: Wanting the red rectangle to be removed from the scene once the black square collides with it. It also takes you to the next frame upon doing so. here is my code.

```
 addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler);
 function fl_EnterFrameHandler (event:Event):void
    {
        if (player.hitTestObject(Risk))
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler);
            removeChild(Risk);
            nextFrame();                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Given you 6 rep, waiting for someone else upvotes your question, so you can submit us your nice images :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you forget about `Scenes`! They are old, buggy, bring loads of issues with code and are generally a Bad Pratice!! So if you are just learning `AS3`, dont learn with `Scenes`!!
Use `MovieClips` or `Sprites` instead. And just add and remove them as you need!

EDIT:
To ur edit ;)

> and seen as Flash itself will be outdated soon

thats just plain false and a widespread misinformation. It just has a new purpose like MultiPlattform Game Development. But thats a whole different discussion.

You could solve this by saving the x,y coordinates and then restoring them. But i promise you, you will run in to alot more problems/bugs as you go allong!

Like saved Points and Time. Will you triger the Questionscene again when u place the player on the object(last Position). Save the answers, and so on ...
Changing to DisplayObjects will save you time in the end. Just saying ;)

EDIT2:

your code in the comment should look like this:

```
function fl_EnterFrameHandler (event:Event):void
        {
            if (player.hitTestObject(Risk))
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler);//remove to prevent errors if it fires again and there is no Object to hitTest
                removeChild(Risk);// do what needs to be done on this frame
                nextFrame();// and then move to the next                
            }
        }
```

And following correct convetions and make everybody's life easier reading this, it would look like this!

```
function fl_EnterFrameHandler (event:Event):void
        {
            if (player.hitTestObject(risk))
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler);//remove to prevent errors if it fires again and there is no Onject to hitTest
                removeChild (risk);
                nextFrame ();

            }
        }
```

i'm probaly confusing u now, just use the top one ;)

**EDIT3:**
Ok, i just had a butchers at it. It's all on a single Frame now. I would have prefered Classes but that'lljust confuse you.

To add new qestions you just have to dublicate the Question MovieClip in the Library and change texts, leave instance names the same tho, then the code will work as is!
[DOWLOAD](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/43532071/files/TheWorkEscapebeta.fla)

Comment: Quote! Not using scenes since Flash MX

Comment: I am going to run into loads of trouble arent I, especially seen as ill be repeating this progress of bumping into objects - directed to the risk assesment scene - return back to the maze scene with player coordinates restored. Oh man oh man oh man. I dont know the first thing about displayobjects, sadface. I can see what you mean about re-entering the question scene upon restore, Ill have to make the collision object appear off stage once returned to the maze scene wont I?

Comment: DisplayObjects are objects that can be displayed ;) In this case a MovieClip or Sprite! Just make a new MovieClip and copy/paste the content of your scene into it. Including the actionsScript layer if your coding on the timeline!
And yes, remove the object on hitTest

Comment: Alright Ill give it a whirl although you should know I am not entirely comfortable with this! Youre still an absolute Don for helping me out though. Thanks mate

Comment: Hi MatchBoxer? You there? Ive adopted the method you described and as anticipated I need to remove the object on hitTest. However im having a right nightmare trying to figure out how to do it. I tried the remove child method i found a tut online but to no avail :( Ill edit the original post with new images of my scene with it all on the timeline now. thaaanks

Comment: Alright! I'm here ;) you will have to show some code. removeChild() is the right way 4ward!

Comment: Haha awesome, rapid response! okay so i figured you simply add the remove child in to the collision function like so ..

function fl_EnterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
 if (player.hitTestObject(risk)){
  
  nextFrame();
  removeChild(risk);
 }
}

and have a variable - var Risk:MovieClip = new risk();

Comment: hard to read here, could u update your question, would make it easier!
But from what i can tell, you should removeChild(Risk); since thats what you called your risk() Class. and you should do that before the nextFrame() call! I'll update my answer! who knows, it might get accepted as corrext .. hehe
btw there a also some typing convetions you should follow. instance names start with a small letter and Classes with a capital, makes it way more easy to read

Comment: uuups .. you removed most of the question, i kow somehow u can roll back.

Comment: Yaaaay i got it to remove child but now it doesnt take me to the next frame :( I put the removeChild(Risk) before the nextFrame() call like you said by the way

Comment: are u getting an error?!?
btw, to rool back edits, click on "edited 11 mins ago "

Comment: yeah im getting:Line 83 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Risk.

Comment: I thought that .. ive already updatet the awnswer! ;) should work^^

Comment: Ohhh man im still getting the same error is it something to do with the variable: var Risk:MovieClip = new risk();

Comment: is that the line 83?
how are u adding the "risk"? with addChild or did you just drag it on stage?

Comment: then delete this line -> var Risk:MovieClip = new risk();   click on the red box and in the field <instance name> type Risk

Comment: I already had the instance name risk, changed it to Risk and still the exact same error: call to an undefined method Risk. I feel so dumb, do I need to do an addChild as well then?

Comment: did u delete the line like i said? dragging it on stage and giving it the name, basicly does the exact same! u cant have both. the name must be the same u use in your code and it must exist on the stage when yur reffrence it from the code

Comment: and no, no need for addChild here

Comment: Yeah i did exactly what you said, now Im not getting any errors but nothing at all is happening, its not removing child and its not piking up the collision =S im so stumped Ill edit the code at the top to show you what i have

Comment: Oh it was because i missed this line from the top :addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler);
But now all thats happening is the child being removed, i dont move to the next frame

Comment: hmm, real hard to tell without the project. make a trace and see if the hittest is fired correct. above removeEvenntListener, put: trace("hit"); and see if it comes in the output

Comment: yeah hit was returned in the output, I also just put nextFrame(); above the removeEventListener but it is still only removing the child

Comment: ok, you will have stop() in your nextframe, so change nextFrame(); to play();

Comment: or gotoAndStop("Scene1"); ... getting there ;)

Comment: wtf?! mate, i would realy need to see the whole thing, it's kinda hard guessing on this end. where do you jump back to? btw ur still not using the method i meant initially, your still jumping around on frames, which is whats causing all this problems

Comment: Hey that finally worked nice! Except now when i return to the maze my player has disappeared lol and the red box (risk) reappears too!

Comment: fancy uploading it to dropbox or somwhere? i think it would save us both a ton of time. i promise i wont sell it :D

Comment: Yeah sure man whats your email, Ive dropped it in my public folder mate this well appreciated! andy3wood@googlemail.com

Comment: hmm, dont rly want my mail on here. just put it in public folder and send the link. if u dont want it here, just delete after i got it. wont take a minute

Comment: got it. u can delete now if u want

Comment: I'll have a look at it now, but will fix it 2morrow. getting kinda late, and there will be quite some rearanging. i'll send it 2morrow

Comment: Okay thanks a lot mate youre being a massive help, ciao for now (:

Comment: Sorry mate been away from a PC for a couple o days! Thats awesome this is defiantly a more efficient way to structure a flash app, Thanks a lot man I really appreciate it!

Comment: no worries. You could accept the anwser tho ;) need some brownie points for a bounty ...

Comment: ooo sorry mate! Ho do I do that? So very new to this, want to give you all the brownie points i can!

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible. You would store the characters attributes (e.g. current position) within a variable. Then on returning to your game you would use this variable to set the starting position of your character.

I agree that scenes are not the ideal route you should be taking. Possibly reading a good AS3 book would save you hours/days/weeks in the long run.